# WCF message filtering

Tags: .net, wcf, logging, soap, diagnostics

When message logging is enabled i can see them all but need filtering:

```
<MessageLogTraceRecord>
<Addressing>
    <Action>http://myuri/IManager/getData</Action>
    <To>http://localhost/MyService.svc</To>
</Addressing>

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <getData xmlns="http://myuri/IManager">
              ............
        </getData>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
</MessageLogTraceRecord>
```

The above is what i see in the log when calling Java web service over http. Note, there is no SOAP header so i cannot filter by action name like in [the sample from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx). However, filtering by body is prohibited. OK, i tried these XPath expressions (and many many others):

```
<filters>
    <add>/Addressing/Action[contains(text(), "http://myuri/IManager/getData")]</add>
    <add xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">/soap:Envelope[not(soap:Header)]</add>
<filters>
```

But still all messages were logged (WCF considered it bad and removed?). The questions are:

1. Why there is no SOAP header (the rest of messages transferred over net.tcp have it)?
2. How to write XPath to filter `getData` calls only?

Comment: I believe the reason your filter isn't working is because filtering is applied to the SOAP message.  You're attempting to filter against the Addressing element which is part of the message trace record.  Unfortunately, without a header, I don't have any suggestions on how to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the post with one of the filters i tried - it didn't work.